# A Little strtok() Fun

Tags: c, strtok

I am not the best with pointers, so maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Let's say that I have an array that was initialized like this:

```
char *arrayOfCommands[]={"ls -l", "wc -l"};
```

My goal is to get an array called **char *currentCommand** out of this array that looks at a specific cell of arrayOfCommands and separates the command into pieces on spaces.

My final goal would be to have a new currentCommand array on each loop that each look like this:

```
First Loop:  
currentCommand = [ls][-l]

First Loop:  
currentCommand = [wc][-l]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    char str[] = arrayOfCommands[i];
    char * currentCommand;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    currentCommand = strtok (str, " ");
    while (currentCommand != NULL){
        printf ("%s\n",currentCommand);
        currentCommand = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    .
    .
    .

    //Use the currentCommand array (and be done with it)
    //Return to top
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**UPDATE:**

```
for (i = 0; i < commands; ++i) {
    char str[2];
    strncpy(str, arrayOfCommands[i], 2);
    char *currentCommand[10];
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    currentCommand = strtok (str, DELIM);
    while (currentCommand != NULL){
        printf ("%s\n",currentCommand);
        currentCommand = strtok (NULL, DELIM);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:  ** incompatible types in assignment**
It's talking about the "str" I'm passing the strtok function.

Comment: Are you sure `strtok()` is the best choice? Have you considered using `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()` or something similar instead?  `strtok()` is a dangerous function. If you use it in a library function, you must document that you do so because by using it, you wreak havoc on anyone who calls your function while themselves using `strtok()`. And you must also be careful not to call any other function that uses `strtok()` for the same reason. Generally, steer well clear of `strtok()` unless there's a teacher holding your hands in the flames and forcing you to keep them there  Look for `strtok_r()`.

Comment: What does `char str[] = arrayOfCommands[i];` mean?

Comment: You seem to be getting strings, arrays of char, and arrays of pointers conflated in several places.  Maybe as a first step you can code up something that takes a single command string and parses it into an array of tokens. Make a that a function, and now you have something that you can call for each item in your `arrayOfCommands[]`.  On second thought, for the first step just print each token on a separate line before trying to build an array of tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` operates by modifying the string that you pass; this is easy to miss when using some man pages. Each command in your array is a literal string: attempts to modify them will cause problems. So you'll need to make a *copy* of each command before using it with `strtok`.

Furthermore, this is an invalid initialization for an array:

```
char str[] = arrayOfCommands[i];
```

Declare `str` as an array of some fixed size, then use `strncpy` to make copies of each command before tokenizing them using `strtok`:

```
char str[MAX_COMMAND_LEN + 1];
strncpy(str, arrayOfCommands[i], MAX_COMMAND_LEN);

// ...
```

Comment: Easy to miss? Always read BUGS section. http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtok.3.html#bugs

Comment: @VladLazarenko that's only one example. Not every man page has that section.

Comment: strncpy was intended for use with UNIX directory entries, which were 14-byte arrays that had to be nul-padded but not nul-terminated. It's never the right solution for anything else, as it 1) NUL-pads, which isn't necessary and 2) fails to NUL-terminate, which results in UB.

Comment: @pb2q I've updated my code, but I'm still getting one, small error.  Is there a way around it?  (Sorry I'm not the best at this!)

Comment: @Rick_Sch it's because of how you've declared `currentCommand`: `strtok` passes back a `char *`, but `currentCommand _isn't_ a `char *`. Also, your `str` is too small: only 2 characters for each command, and finally your usage of `strncpy` can fail to null-terminate `str`.

Comment: @pb2q I'm sorry. I'm just SO new to C and I'm not understanding. How do I declare `currentCommand` then?